# Qt 4.8.2. Ошибка профиля. Профиль Qt не установлен выполните make Install

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Учу версию Qt 4.8.2 (сам бы выбрал 5, но на кафедре "Привыкли к 4.8.2").

Поставил ее на виртуальную машину так как у меня Windows 10. MinGW 4.4 под эту версию тоже нашел. Никаких ошибок и предупреждений при установке не было QtCreator 2.6.2 поставил.

Вроде бы должно все работать, но при добавлении qmake в профили, просит выполнить какой-то make install. Как его выполнить? Помогите, пожалуйста. Уже неделю не могу заставить все это работать по-человечески. Вот скриншоты.

Kits

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Профили Qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да и еще вопрос: при создании проекта разве не должны появляться Комплекты и все сопутствующее?

Пошагово создаю проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В последнем окне нет возможности ничего добавить в проект.

Comment: Если пользоваться MinGW, то Qt 4.8 на Windows сам ставит 4.4 версию и делает автоопределение профиля. Я недавно устанавливал, правда оффлайн-установщиком. Из коробки все работало.

Comment: Смотрите внимательно, **что именно** вы создаете. Что за *файл ресурсов*, если вопрос про комплекты и проект?

Comment: @Bogdan Вопрос и про make install и про проект. Создаю QT .grc Для добавления в проект виджитов .

Comment: @Bogdan Официально через онлайн MinGW 4.4 уже не поставляется,

Comment: виджеты форм к файлам ресурсов не имеют никакого отношения

Comment: На первом скрине в комбобоксе, в котором указывается компилятор, написано "*компилятор недоступен*". Вы добавили его на вкладке "компиляторы"?

Comment: @Bogdan нет. Сейчас добавляю. Какой именно exe ставить? При добавлении MinGW

Comment: Ставьте `g++.exe`, потом проверьте путь к `qmake`. И затем укажите в настройках компилятор.

Comment: @Bogdan Все равно пишет, что компилятор недоступен

Comment: Тогда попробуйте удалить текущий профиль и создать его заново, соответствующе настраивая

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89601/discussion-between-konstantin-sh-and-bogdan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь, что Профиле указан путь до qmake.exe, расположенный в (вашем случае) C:\Qt\4.8.2\bin\qmake.exe

у вас же указан путь C:\Qt\4.8.2\qmake\qmake.exe